# Cheat to unlock all gadgets in Batman: Arkham City?

Tags: batman-arkham-city, cheats

I was watching YouTube recently and saw a guy who pressed the <kbd>F1</kbd> and got all the weapons at the very first mission.

He proposed adding `bminput.ini` in the game files. I added this but nothing has changed. How do I get all the gadgets?

EDIT : Sorry. it`s actually Batman : Arkham Origins...

Is there something similar for Arkham City ?

Comment: I imagine that `vtimput.ini` had some text in it, could you paste this here? And potentially link to the Youtube video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such way to cheat in Batman : Arkham City. Sorry !

Comment: Any explanation for this, maybe?

Comment: Like, and explanation of what you *cannot* do in the game ?

Comment: More like a source.

Comment: Well, it is always quite hard to prove something is impossible. As far as I know, no one found a way to accomplish what was asked here ; this might changed someday.